# Android weekly file download or startIntent feature

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

So I'm writing an application which downloads a CSVFile from a `CSVDownloader` class that I have created.

Now currently my app just waits for the file download and waits on `SplashActivity` and then moves on. This can be lengthy and tiresome every time one loads the app so what I want to do is basically **compare the timestamp date with the date value in a week's time (i.e. +7) and only download the file if the original file is a week old.**

Could someone take a look at my code and suggest modifications to make this plausible?

`SplashActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    Thread thread = new CSVDownloader(this);
    thread.start();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    //make spinner and make run
}
```

And the `CSVDownloader` thread task:

```
package uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import uk.ac.aber.dwd.CeredigionTourism.SplashActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

/**
 * CSVDownloader extends Thread and will download CSV records and turn them into Map/List markers.
 * @author danieldrave
 *
 */
 public final class CSVDownloader extends Thread {

private SplashActivity splashActivity;

/**
 * @param splashActivity
 */
public CSVDownloader(SplashActivity splashActivity) {
    this.splashActivity = splashActivity;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    String filePath = downloadCSVFile();
    BufferedReader buffer;

    if(filePath == null){
        System.err.println("File Path was null");
        return;
    }

    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(splashActivity);

    try {
        buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
        String line = buffer.readLine(); //read first line because its headers and discard
        String relLine;

        while ((relLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            while(relLine.contains("\t\t"))
                relLine = relLine.replace("\t\t","\t \t"); //REPLACE FUNCTION FOR SPACE BETWEEN TABS
            String[] str = relLine.split("\t");
            if(str.length < 9){
                System.err.println("My client got it wrong");
                System.err.println(str);
                continue;
            }

            MapMarker marker = new MapMarker();
            marker.setGroup(str[0]);
            marker.setName(str[1]);
            marker.setImage(str[2]);
            marker.setDescription(str[3]);
            marker.setAddress(str[4]);
            marker.setTelephone(str[5]);
            marker.setUrl(str[6]);
            marker.setLatitude(str[7]);
            marker.setLongitude(str[8]);

            db.addMapMarker(marker); //ADD COMPLETED MAP MARKER WITH INDEXED COLUMN VALUES
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("FILE DOWNLOADED: " + filePath);
}

private String downloadCSVFile() {

    final String filename = "locations.csv";
    String filePath = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

try {   
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(null, -1),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.cardigan.cc/app/locations.csv");  

        //GET FILE FROM URL AND WRITE TO LOCATIONS.CSV LOCALLY
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
            filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +filename;
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
            int inByte;
            while((inByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(inByte);
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        }

        else if(entity == null) {
            System.out.println("NO FILE DOWNLOADED FROM SERVER");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filePath;                
}
}
```

Any help anyone could provide would be marvellous, thank you.

Comment: Can you store the last time the file was downloaded and use that date or you need to check if the file is older then 1 week? Can you add the time the file was created on the header response?

Comment: @GhostDerfel it would be perfectly to use the date the file was downloaded. And then I want to compare it to the date in a week's time. So I assume something like `dateDownloaded <= dateDownloaded +7` around that logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `file.lastModified()` method to get the last modified date of the `locations.csv` on your device and compare the date. And if it's more than a week's old, run the `downloadCSV()` method.

Some code out of my head:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), your_file_name);

Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());

//... use lastModified to check date
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and the [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) objects for this.

This will get the job done for you and adjust your Splash to not finish until after 1.5 seconds.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    if(shouldUpdateCSV()){
        Thread thread = new CSVDownloader(this);
        thread.start();
        updateLastCheckedDate(context); // Call this after you've completed your CSVDownload, not just after starting the Thread to make sure it actually does update.
    }

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1500); // Use postDelayed to have it post to the main thread after x milliseconds
}

public boolean shouldUpdateCSV(){
    return new Date().getTime() - getLastCheckedDate() > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
}

public long getLastCheckedDate(){
    return getSharedPreferences("preference_name", 0).getLong("pref_last_checked_timestamp", 0);
}

public static void updateLastCheckedDate(Context context){
    context.getSharedPreferences("preference_name", 0).edit().putLong("pref_last_checked_timestamp", new Date().getTime()).commit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store your download data, after you complete your file download add something like that:

```
SharedPreferences sp =  context.getSharedPreferences("filedetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
shared.putLong(MY_STATIC_STRING_TO_REFERENCE,System.currentTimeInMillis());
editor.commit();
```

Then before you start your download you can check the date like that:

```
SharedPreferences sp= context.getSharedPreferences("filedetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
long lastDownload= userDetails.getString(MY_STATIC_STRING_TO_REFERENCE, null);
long today = System.currentTimeInMillis();
if((lastDownload+1000*60*60*24*7)<today){
   //Do download
}
```

All code was done directly on Stack Overflow so can contain some errors, sorry ;(